# Filter repeated elements RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm working with a **huge** **RDD** and I'd like to filter it following a rule. I have a **RDD** with two elements and I don't mind the order of the factors, so I could filter it in order to **remove** those **repeated** pairs.

My input data is something like this:

```
{{A,B},{A,C},{B,A},{B,C},{C,A},{C,B}}
```

And the output filtered RDD should be this one:

```
{{A,B},{A,C},{B,C}}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd apply a .map step to the RDD that sorts the elements in your tuples. so that [(A,C), (C, A)] turns into [(A,C), (A, C)]

after that you can do a .distinct to get all the unique values.

Comment: Could you give me any clue? Do I have to apply cartesian to RDD to do that?

Comment: ```val newRdd = oldRdd.map(myValue => { myValue /* apply custom sort logic here */ }).distinct``` Just the map and the distinct operators ... no cartesian anything needed.